# Xamarin Microsoft.Identity.Client AuthenticationResult AccessToken is null

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms PCL application that uses Azure B2C to authenticate users.  I was previously using `Microsoft.Identity.Client` version 1.0.304142221-alpha but I just updated to 1.1.0-preview after it came out on NuGet.

I'm also using the Azure `MobileServiceClient` to login users so only authenticated users can make calls to my tables.

I am able to successfully authenticate, which I set up like [this sample on GitHub.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native)

Using the previous version of `Microsoft.Identity.Client`, I was able to login to the `MobileServiceClient` like this:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Config.Scopes, 
         string.Empty, UiOptions.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, 
         Config.Authority, Config.SignUpSignInpolicy);

JObject payload = getPayload(ar.IdToken);
payload["access_token"] = ar.Token;
string objectId = payload["oid"].ToString();

MobileServiceUser u = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,
                      payload);
```

However, after the update, `AuthenticationResult` no longer has a member named `Token`.  Instead, it has `AccessToken`, which for me, is always returning `null`.

I have tried logging into the `MobileServiceClient` using the `IdToken`, but this produces an unauthorized error.

I think this problem could have something to with the scopes I define.  Right now I have:

```
public static string[] Scopes = { "https://<MyTennant>/<MyAPIName>.read"};
```

Are there any scopes that I'm missing to get the `AccessToken` or is the problem somewhere else?

**Update: Here are my settings in the Azure Portal**
For my API:
[image: My Azure B2C API Settings]

For my Native Client:
[image: My Azure B2C Native Client Settings]

In my App, I'm logging in like this:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, 
                     GetUserByPolicy(App.AuthenticationClient.Users, PolicySignUpSignIn),
                     App.UiParent);
payload = getPayload(ar.IdToken);
payload["access_token"] = ar.IdToken;

var mobileService = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient("https://giftthis.azurewebsites.net/.auth/");
MobileServiceUser u = await mobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

`LoginAsync` is now executing, but it returns null so I still can't make calls to the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to test this issue using the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` version 1.1.0-preview, however it works well for me.

The mobile app was protected using Azure AD B2C app with **Advanced** mode and set the **ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES** using the app id like figure below:
[image]

After that I used the `MobileServiceClient` from [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/). And to new the `MobileServiceClient` we only need to provide the mobile application URL as code below:

```
string applicationUrl = "https://mobilefei.azurewebsites.net/";
var mobileClient = new MobileServiceClient(applicationUrl);
```

However if I used the `MobileServiceClient` from [Azure Mobile Services SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/)
, I can reproduce the same issue with **401** error. In this scenario, when we need append `.auth` to initialize the `MobileServiceClient` like code below:

```
string applicationUrl = "https://mobilefei.azurewebsites.net/.auth/";
var mobileClient = new MobileServiceClient(applicationUrl);
```

### Update:

```
string CLIENT_ID = "420a3a24-97cf-46ca-a882-f6c047b0d845";
string[] SCOPES = { "https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/b2cwebapp/read" };
string Tenant = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com";

string PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1_Sign_In";
string AuthorityBase = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}";


PublicClientApplication myApp = new PublicClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, Authority);

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = myApp.AcquireTokenAsync(SCOPES).Result;

Console.WriteLine($"AccessToken:\n{authenticationResult.AccessToken}");

Console.WriteLine($"IdToken:\n{authenticationResult.IdToken}");

//This applicationUrl  works for WindowsAzure.MobileServices
//string applicationUrl = "https://mobilefei.azurewebsites.net/.auth/";

//This applicationUrl  works for Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client
string applicationUrl = "https://mobilefei.azurewebsites.net/";
var mobileClient = new MobileServiceClient(applicationUrl);

JObject token = new JObject();
token.Add("access_token", authenticationResult.IdToken);
var user = mobileClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, token).Result;
Console.WriteLine($"UserID:\n{user.UserId}");
Console.Read();
```

Comment: How are you logging into the mobileClient?  I'm using the AuthenticationResult returned from Microsoft.Identity.Client PublicClientApplication.LoginAsync() and then adding "access_token" to the JObject with the IdToken returned in the AuthenticaitonResult.  With those changes, I'm still getting unauthorized.

Comment: I just login the mobileClient using the `LoginAsync` and provide the id_token as you mentioned.  Which library are you using? I suggest that you capture the request using the Fiddler to check whether the endpoint is correct since the different library is a litter different as I mentioned in the post.  It will miss the `.auth` in the request path like `https://{HostURL}/login/aad`. And I also updating the testing code sample, if you still have the problem, please also share the settings on Azure for the mobile app.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices and I do have the .auth

Comment: I'll add my settings quick and show how I'm currently calling it

Comment: I got it to finish the LoginAsync method, I had added the wrong App Id to my Allowed Token Audiences.  However, LoginAsync is returning a null MobileServiceUser so something is still wrong.

Comment: Also, will I be able to make calls to `GetTable` when I add /.auth/ to the URL?

Comment: No, it will not able to call the `GetTable` since the it will add `.auth` to the URL. And to troubleshoot the null issue for return user, I suggest that you capture the request using Fiddler to see whether the response is correct. I am testing using the `WindowsAzure.MobileServices.1.3.2`, it rerun the user successfully.  And to make the code also could retrieve the tables successfully, I suggest that you using the `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` with latest version `4.0.0` since the `WindowsAzure.MobileServices` SDK is Deprecated.

Comment: You can install the Azure Mobile Client SDK 4.0.0 using the command `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client`

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client version 4.0.0 doesn't target profile 7 which is what I'm using, so I can only install it on my iOS and Android projects and not the PCL.

Comment: I got it to work with version 4.0.0-alpha (which doesn't make sense but whatever) and without using the `.auth` in the url.