# why the accessToken is null in AuthenticationResult B2C authentication?

Tags: c#, api, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a xamarin.form project. I add the B2C authentication according to this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c
I copy and paste exactly and did not change the methods. now it works but the problem is in AuthenticationResult ar parameter, the access token is null and also the expiry date is also wrong. I can not solve it.[I attached the image of AuthenticationResult content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yudj.jpg)
please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the wrong scope value. Access tokens are for accessing protected resources, like web apis. Scopes are the way to manage permissions to those protected resources. Scopes are used by the web api to implement scope-based access control.

For example, to specify the Scope Value of `read` for the API that has the App ID URI of `https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/api`, the scope would be `https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/api/read`.

In the AAD B2C portal, you would set all of this up.

For example, in this sample, the client app is asking for permission to this [apiEndpoint](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Core/App.xaml.cs#L11) `https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello`
through [this scope](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Core/Features/LogOn/B2CConstants.cs#L13) `https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read`

which is set up in the AAD B2C section of the portal. In my Web Api (called HelloApi), I set up the scopes:
[image]

Then in the same AAD B2C section, I go to my client app, (called AzureAD B2C Playground), and in the section called "API access" I add a link to the HelloApi, and determine which scopes this application will have access to.
[image]

Back in the client app, I need to make sure I have the clientId set, the policies and the redirect Uri, and have updated the values for the Web API scope and the ApiEndpoint. Now that everything is connected in the AAD B2C portal, you should be getting back an Access Token for that resource (the Web Api).

See [this sample for details](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native)

See [access tokens in AAD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens)

See [scopes in AAD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#scopes)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this to create a Web API App reg to represent your Resource, and assign your front App Reg end access to the resource (permission). 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application?tabs=applications

Then the auth request must provide the API Identifier and Scope name in the scope parameter of the authentication request to obtain an auth code which will be redeemed for an access token:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens

To get MSAL to do this for you, do this:
`AuthenticationResult result = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())`

The scope will be an array and must contain the Identifier URI/ScopeName of the Web API App Reg you setup above.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/e546c7cbc8ed20b724e742598bffac68b25c7f88/WebServices/AzureADB2CAuth/ADB2CAuthorization/LoginPage.xaml.cs#L25

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure , you have done the following steps:

- In Azure B2C Blade select Application and set the Reply URL to the address of the Azure Mobile Apps instance `(e.g. https://App.azurewebsites.net), followed by /.auth/login/aad/callback`
- in the blade select the AAD provider, go to advanced and set up Client ID and Issuer URL, with the Client ID being the Application ID of the Azure Active Directory B2C tenant, and the Issuer Url being the Metadata Endpoint for the Azure Active Directory B2C policy

Additional reference:

[Xamarin Microsoft.Identity.Client AuthenticationResult AccessToken is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486836/xamarin-microsoft-identity-client-authenticationresult-accesstoken-is-null)

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/issues/24

Please check the below doc for the right steps:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/commit/076ed31f3af9c82cd131efcc97d32f1c4fe6cb57

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my authentication works well, and my problem is just accessToken, I am working on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your client ID to scopes